# Recent achievement popup reputation broken with upvoted answer linking to own example in documentation

Tags: bug, documentation, reputation

When I open the "Recent achievements: [...]" pop-up, I get the following:

[image]

Which is a `+50` on a SO documentation example, which has currently a score of 0 (1 downvote and 1 upvote I think), but in my profile I see the following:

[image]

As you can see, I actually got `+45` on an answer which linked to the above mentioned example (the `+5` above) - This is the correct display (the answer has 3 upvotes, is accepted and have a link to the example).